# Not updating Meteor.users.update with insecure package and autopublish on

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I've got the following smart-packages installed:

```
standard-app-packages
autopublish
insecure
preserve-inputs
bootstrap-3
accounts-base
accounts-password
jquery
accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
iron-router
```

I'm trying to update the email address for a user, and since i've got the insecure and autopublish packages installed, i thought i could just do that like this:

```
Template.settings.events({
  'click #update': function (evt, tmpl) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var email = tmpl.find("#inputEmail").value;

    Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.userId()}, {$set:{"emails":[{address:email}]}});
  }
});
```

But i keep getting: update failed: Access denied

Answer (score 0):

Mabye this comment out of the docs helps you.

> Users are by default allowed to specify their own profile field with Accounts.createUser and modify it with Meteor.users.update. To allow users to edit additional fields, use Meteor.users.allow. To forbid users from making any modifications to their user document

You try to change the emails field. At first the emails field should be ( if you want to have the email public ) in profile folder. So you have to do something like

```
$set: {
        profile: {
            emails: {

            }
        }
    }
```

If you change another field outside of profile you have to define allow-rules.